# Command Handler Rich Embed TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So recently I tried implementing a command handler into my discord bot. All the commands that had Rich Embeds came up with the error "Cannot read property 'send' of undefined. Send help

Code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const ms = require('ms');
const bot = new Discord.Client();

var botname = 'Dev Bot'
var version = '1.0.0'
var author = 'potato#9347'

module.exports = {
    name: "suggest",
    description: "Sends suggestions to a suggestions channel",
    execute(message, args)
    {
        var suggestion = args.join(" ").slice(8)
        if(!args[1]) return message.reply("You didn't suggest anything")
        const suggestionchannel = "685991785138356458"
        const suggestembed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setTitle('New Suggestion')
        .setColor(0x7289DA)
        .setFooter('Powered by ' + botname + ' ' + version)
        .setTimestamp()
        .addField('Suggestion', suggestion)
        .addField('Suggested by:', message.author)
        bot.channels.get(suggestionchannel).send(suggestembed).then(sentEmbed =>{
            sentEmbed.react('')
            sentEmbed.react('')

        message.reply("Thank you for the suggestion")
        setTimeout(() => {
            message.channel.bulkdelete(2)
          }, 1000);
        }
    )}
}
```

Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined

Comment: The only property `send` you access here is `bot.channels.get(suggestionchannel).send`, so that would mean that `bot.channels.get(suggestionchannel)` is undefined, which would make me think that it cannot find the channel with ID `685991785138356458`.

Comment: would you know why that would be?

Comment: I don't know, log what `bot.channels` contains and see what channels there are...

Comment: when I `console.log(suggestionchannel)` it gives the channel ID but if I `console.log(bot.channels.get(suggestionchannel))` it gives me undefined????????

Comment: this only seems to happen in the command handler aswell

Comment: What do you get with `console.log(bot.channels.filter(x => true))`? You should get all channels that _do_ exist, so maybe this gives you a hint why yours isn't found.